# How does HLS video on iOS pick which rendition to start out with?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, http-live-streaming

I heard from a WWDC video that it measures the speed of previous HLS downloads to pick which rendition to use, but how does it choose which one to use at the very start? Is the download speed of the file for the list of renditions or the download speed of the file for a specific rendition used at all? I want to make sure that I'm not tricking the video player into using too high quality of a rendition by loading metadata files instantly from the cache.

Comment: @JAL these sorts of things are commonly discussed in WWDC videos and other publications by Apple

Answer (score 1):

It picks the first entry:

> *The first entry in the variant playlist will be played at the initiation of a stream* and is used as part of a test to determine which stream is most appropriate. The order of the other streams is irrelevant. *Therefore, the first bit rate in the playlist should be the one that most clients can sustain.*

From the **Bit rate recommendations** section of Apple's **Technical Note TN2224**: 
[Best Practices for Creating and Deploying HTTP Live Streaming Media for the iPhone and iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-BITRATERECOMMENDATIONS)